# Zoom and current location not showing in map swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am developing a simple app that will have a map and some markers shown in it. I also want the current location of the user to be shown in this app. 
Here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class HomePageViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var templabelforlocationtesting: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true

        //temporary nearby locations list

        //temple tooth
        let templeToothMarker = MKPointAnnotation()
        let templeToothLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 7.294715, longitude: 80.639858)
        templeToothMarker.coordinate = templeToothLocation
        templeToothMarker.title = "Kandy Dalada Maligawa"
        templeToothMarker.subtitle = "Historic Religious place"

        //botanical gardens

        let botanicalGardenMarker = MKPointAnnotation()
        let botanicalGardenLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 7.273346, longitude: 80.595140)
        botanicalGardenMarker.coordinate = botanicalGardenLocation
        botanicalGardenMarker.title = "Royal Botanical Gardens"
        botanicalGardenMarker.subtitle = "Botanical Garden in Kandy"

        //load markers to map
        map.addAnnotations([templeToothMarker, botanicalGardenMarker])

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation

        let centerLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        templabelforlocationtesting.text = "Location: " + String(location.coordinate.latitude) + " , " + String(location.coordinate.longitude)

        let mapSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.06, 0.06)

        let mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerLocation, span: mapSpan)

        self.map.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }


}
```

The map is working and the markers are showing, but the following issues persist.

1. I cannot get the map to zoom to a higher level (to the level set in `let mapSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.06, 0.06)`)
2. The current location of the user should be obtained and set as the centre of the map and should also show as the current location with an annotation. To check if the location is loaded, I have set a label as well,  but this doesn't work too.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you put a break point at **let location = locations.last! as CLLocation** what values do you get?

Answer (score 3):

This code structure is always wrong:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // ...
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

The problem is that it takes many calls to `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` before you get a usable location. But you are stopping unconditionally after the *first* call, which is just about certain to be useless.

Also, you should never tell the map `self.map.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)` if you are *also* telling it to `self.map.showsUserLocation = true`. The map will set *itself* to show the right area if its `showsUserLocation` is `true`. In fact, if all you want to do is set the map to the user's location, you should not be updating locations with the location manager at all. Let the map view do all the work.

Comment: I use also `self.map.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)` and `showsUserLocation = true` but I do not set user's current location in first launch